# Wine tasting probabilities

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I just want to make sure that my solutions are correct.

Problem statement:
In a Napa Valley winery, guests are invited to a tasting room, and, for each of them, an
affable staff member pours 6 types of wine, which are sold at different prices, in 6 small
3-ounce stylish glasses, at random and one at a time. What is the probability that the first
three glasses of wine they serve a visitor (a) are, in order, the three most expensive of
the 6 brands he or she tastes; (b) are the most expensive brands, but not necessarily in
order of their prices?

Total number of permutations : $6!$

a.) $\frac{3!}{6!}$ since the first 3 wines are fixated in a specific order, so we only have $3!$ permutations.

b.) $\frac{3!+3!}{6!}$ since the first 3 wines have $3!$ permutations but are fixated as going first, and the second part of the 6 wines also have $3!$ permutations.

Comment: Why are you *adding* the two $3!$ terms in the numerator in (b)?

Comment: My thought process is that we have 3! different orders for the 3 most expensive wines. And then we have 3! different orders for the remaining 3 wines. Multiply it instead?

Comment: I would write some suitable sequences down and see if you can figure out how it should go. Alternatively, you can figure out, at the first turn, the second turn, and the third turn, what the probability is of choosing a qualifying wine at each turn (for both (a) and (b)).

Comment: For b), I have to multiply because for each permutation of the first 3 wines, I have 6 permutations of the last 3 wines. I dont know why I added it. Makes sense now.

Comment: @swisstackle For b), my thought would lead to the answer $\dfrac{1}{\binom 63}$, which matches your latest comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chance that the first wine is the most expensive is one in six, the chance that the second wine is the second most expensive, given that the first is the most expensive, is one in five, since there are only five wines to choose from, and the chance that the third is the third most expensive is one in four.
$$
1/6\times1/5\times1/4={3!\over 6!}
$$
You can also do that combinatorically, but the argument is so easy in this case.

The second case is easier to do with combinatorics; there are $6!$ ways that the wines could come, and $3!\times3!$ ways they could come in the two specified sets.